# Where can I find the Hybrid Sleep option in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, power-management, hybrid-sleep

My question is related to this question [What is Hybrid Sleep in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/62331/what-is-hybrid-sleep-in-windows-7)

Seems I don't have the option on my laptop:
- Gateway MT6826j
- Windows 7 Ultimate (upgrade from Vista Ultimate)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have hibernation enabled, as hybrid sleep requires hibernation support to save the memory content to the hard drive.

Check if you have a file named hiberfil.sys in the root for your boot disk. If you don't have it, hibernation is not enabled.

To enable it, run the command from an elevated command prompt:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate on
```